# rabbit-c Consume message from default exchange

Tags: c, rabbitmq

Am trying to consume message from a queue which has binding to default exchange.

rabbit-c client requires exchange name and tried with the following options

option 1 : setting the exchange name as empty string ( "" ) as suggested in RMQ Docs

option 2 : passing amqp_empty_bytes in the place of exchange name.

For both options

amqp_queue_bind method is failing with reply code 3.

Is it possible to consume from a default exchange using rabbit-c client?

Note: Queue is already created

Answer (score 1):

amqp_bind_queue was not needed since the queue was already binded to an exchange. Calling amqp_basic_consume works directly.